# Complex function (find u and v)

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't have an idea how to find the real and imaginary part of the following functions:

$$\dfrac{1}{z},~\dfrac{2z-i}{iz+2},~\dfrac{z}{z^2+1},~\ln |z|$$

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please edit and TeX properly your $4$ examples. [See here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help. I have a small screen and I can barely read. Most likely I'm not alone in this case.

Answer (score 3):

For 9, 11 and 12 the same trick applies:
$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{f(z)\bar{g}(z)}{g(z)\bar{g}(z)} = |g(z)|^{-2} f(z)\bar{g}(z)$.
Use the fact that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\Re(az) = a\Re(z)$ and $\Im(az) = a\Im(z)$.

For 13, note that $|z|\in[0,\infty)$, what does this say about $\ln|z|$?

Comment: I made my answer somewhat more explicit. Can you find the answer now?

Comment: 4) u = (x^2-y^2)^1/2  v = 0 
5) Rez?? I thought it means, real part of Z. z = x+iy --> u =x? 
6) u = e^x * cosy  v = e*x siny

Comment: Those answers are correct.

Comment: hmm,ok..Now I'm trying to find others.

Comment: I am also not able to do 7  

$$ coshz = e^z+e^-z/2 = (e^x * e^iy + e^-x * e^-iy)/2 $$

Comment: If you use your result for 6) the answer shouldn't be too hard. Use $\Re(f+g) = \Re(f)+\Re(g)$ and $\Im(f+g) = \Im(f)+\Im(g)$.

Comment: 7) The answer is $$ e^xcosy $$ ?

Comment: Not quite, $u = \frac{e^x\cos(y)+e^{-x}\cos(-y)}{2} = \cosh(x)\cos(y)$.

Comment: I don't really understand how did u get $$ cosh(x)cos(y) $$

Comment: Since $\cos(-y) = \cos(y)$, we have $\frac{e^x\cos(y)+e^{-x}\cos(-y)}{2} = \cos(y)\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} = \cos(y)\cosh(x)$ by definition of $\cosh$.

Comment: Ok.I got it.Thanks for help! I will post the answer for others now.

Comment: So $$ v = sin(-y)cosh(x) $$ isnt' it?

Comment: Well, since $\sin(-y) = -\sin(y)$ you actually get $v=\frac{e^x\sin(y)+e^{-x}\sin(-y)}{2} = \sin(y)\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} = \sin(y)\sinh(x)$ but the definition of $\sinh$.

Comment: Please solve 11 and 13 for me,I don't know why but I can't do it.